# Getting JS error after changing versions: Uncaught ReferenceError: Xyz is not defined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I was using react-vis library. Their readme file says following:

> If you're working in a non-node environment, you can also directly include the bundle and compiled style using basic html tags.
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-vis/dist/style.css">
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-vis/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> The global `reactVis` object will now be available for you to play around.

When I do exactly that, it works and I was able to use `reactVis` object in my code. It links versions [`1.11.7` from `unpkg`](https://unpkg.com/browse/react-vis@1.11.5/dist/). I wanted to try out version `1.11.5`. So, I tried following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-vis@1.11.5/dist/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/browse/react-vis@1.11.5/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
```

But, now it gives me following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: reactVis is not defined
```

Somehow, it is not able to get reference to `reactVis` code. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you used contains `https://unpkg.com/browse/...` `/browse` links to the html preview page of the file.

To link to the raw version of the file remove `/browse` in your case to `https://unpkg.com/react-vis@1.11.5/dist/dist.min.js`, which would link to the file raw.

eg.

```js
console.log(
  reactVis
)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-vis@1.11.5/dist/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-vis@1.11.5/dist/dist.min.js"></script>
```